# Http response header not getting modified in firefox extension always

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I am modifying the inlinedisposition extension of firefox. Here is the code snippet which actually modifies the header:

```
_httpResponse: function( chan )
{
    var disp = "";


    try {
        chan = chan.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
        disp = chan.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition");
    } catch (e) { }

    if (chan.loadFlags & Components.interfaces.nsIChannel.LOAD_DOCUMENT_URI && this._re.test(disp))
    {
        chan.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", disp.replace(this._re, "inline"), false);
        chan.setResponseHeader("Content-Type", "application/fgdownload", false);  //not working
        }

}
```

**The line which I added to modify the content-type is not working. Content-disposition works fine however.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Content-Type` is one of the response headers that cannot be modified. The others are `Content-Lenght`, `Content-Encoding`, `Trailer` and `Transfer-Encoding`.

However you can change the inherited `contentType` attribute of nsIHttpChannel ([some restrictions apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIChannel#Attributes)).

Comment: is there no way content-type can be changed in firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/force-content-type/ and can we add the content-disposition header to the response, if the response does not contain one.